# Is the back end needed only to produce RESTful API?

Tags: django, rest, frontend, backend

I've just started learning Django and from the first tutorials i've followed or test i've done, it seemed to me (note: i'm a beginner at the whole web developing thing) that you can use it to do anything (back end as well as front end). Now thinking about the many frameworks and libraries for the front end I thought that I was missing something, so after a bit of research i came to the conclusion that the back end part is there only to provide a rest service to use with a front end framework. Do anyone for example uses the templates in Django, if so for what purposes?
Am I missing something about front end - back end integration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got the idea that no-one uses templates in a back-end framework. Of course we do. The vast majority of sites do not use front end frameworks. Even today the idea of rendering everything in Javascript is controversial - see [here](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html?) for a whole range of reasons why it may not be a good idea.

Most sites don't need that level of interactivity, anyway. StackOverflow (although it's done in .NET, not Django, but the concept is the same) is a great example: the bulk of the work is done on the back end using templates, and Javascript is used to add enhancements in the browser, not to do the whole work.

Answer (score -1):

If you're only interested in providing a RESTful webservice, then you'd be better using a lightweight framework, like `flask`. Django provide much more, it comes with a good template system, with well-defined and easy-to-implement models, with powerful routing capabilities, that help you build a website from scratch very fast.

This doesn't mean that you cannot build a RESTful API in Django and use a [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) on the presentation layer.

To answer your question, it all depends on the design of your website. If you're planning to develop a public website that has a lot of content and you want it to be indexed by search engines, then using the Django routes and views helps you accomplish this (not that SPA's can't have SEO, however it's a little bit complex for them).